# AUTO_INCREMENT no longer in phpMyAdmin 4.0.0?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Has the **Operations > Table Options > AUTO_INCREMENT** field been removed from phpMyAdmin? Now that I've upgraded to 4.0.0, I can no longer find it.

**phpMyAdmin 4.0.0** (missing AUTO_INCREMENT)
[image]

**phpMyAdmin 3.5.1** (has AUTO_INCREMENT)
[image]

Comment: It is still there for me.

Comment: It should be under extras.

Comment: Hm.. thanks. I couldn't even get the field to show in the official demo (http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/), so i must be doing something wrong... I thought that normally i just create a table with a column that has the "A_I" box checked, and that would set it up correctly with a Primary Key. But that field just wont show

Comment: Maybe this is a permissions issue

Comment: It is not a permissions issue. There are no permissions which specifically restrict the use of `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: Since when is `AUTO_INCREMENT` a table property and not a column property?

Comment: @nitro2k01 well i don't know the answer to that, all I know is i used to be able to set `AUTO_INCREMENT` and now i can't find it... you can test here: http://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config

Comment: @nitro2k01: A table can only have one `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, and the next value of that column is treated as a property of the table in MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field was accidentally removed from phpMyAdmin 4.0.0 and a bug-fix is [planned to be released in version 4.0.2](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/changelog.php).